# HTML form not able to call PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

```
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="btn-group-justified">
                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-facebook"><span class="fa fa-facebook pull-left"></span>Sign In with Facebook</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div id="my-signin2"></div>
            <script>
            function onSuccess(googleUser) {
                console.log('Logged in as: ' + googleUser.getBasicProfile().getName());
            }
            function onFailure(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
            function renderButton() {
                gapi.signin2.render('my-signin2', {
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
                'width': 270,
                'height': 45,
                'longtitle': true,
                'theme': 'dark',
                'onsuccess': onSuccess,
                'onfailure': onFailure
                });
            }
            </script>
            <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=renderButton" async defer></script>
        </div>
        <div class="signOr">OR</div>
        <form action="logins.php" method="post">
            <p>Email: <input type="email" name="email" /></p>
            <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Sign In" /></p>
        </form>
</div>
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong, but code does not call php but instead, adds the email and password in the web address.

http://www.example.com/?email=xsx%40gmail.com&password=xsaxs#

Comment: I am working on this site and need help lot...www.cyourproperty.com

Comment: Do you acctually have a file that contains the post functions?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at www.cyourproperty.com, you did not close the first form tag (Sign in with Google/Facebook). You just need to add a `</form>` before you start the Email/Password login form.